# Exclude elements from full page CSS .html filter on hover

Tags: css

I was hoping to get some help with a site I'm working on. I'm very new to CSS so excuse if this is basic, but I'm yet to find a solution. I'm sure my head will combust if I keep shooting blind at this issue, I'm creating using cargo.site if it helps.

I have a style filter overlaying the entire site:

```
html {
    -webkit-filter: grayscale(100%);
    -moz-filter: grayscale(100%);
    filter: brightness(80%) sepia(100%) saturate(0.2);
}
```

However, I would like to exclude all images (or elements so I can include embedded videos or pdfs) from these filters on hover so you can see them in full colour. I assume the other option would be to filter only images... if this is easier let me know, but the site looks great currently with a singular filter so everything looks coherent and the other embedded elements look great under the filter too.

I have two lines in the CSS code which relate to images, I'm not sure which one encapsulates all images, so I will leave these here if they help answer.

```
img {
    border: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.content img {
    float: none;
    margin-bottom: 0em;
}
```

Thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

This is unfortunately not possible with a whole page filter like you are currently using. When a filter is applied, it affects all children elements as well.

You could do the grayscale and a color tint with an overlay and a blend mode though. Then whenever you hover over something, you could bump it up above the overlay in z-index to effectively stack it above the color change.

The key factor here is using `pointer-events:none` on the overlays since that will allow the hover events to pass through the overlays and "activate" the images.

You could also sort of simulate the brightness adjustment by setting the images to an opacity lower than 1 as long as the overall background is white.

Check out the following example. It should work fine for videos/iframes as well.

```css
body {display:flex; /*just to stick the images side-by-side*/}

.grayscale {
  background:white;
  mix-blend-mode:color;
  position:fixed;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  z-index:1;
  pointer-events:none;
}

.tint {
  background:tan;
  mix-blend-mode:color;
  position:fixed;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  z-index:2;
  opacity:.5;
  pointer-events:none;
}

img {
  cursor:pointer;
  position:relative;
}

img:hover {
  z-index:3;
}
```

```html
<div class="grayscale"></div>
<div class="tint"></div>
<img src="https://source.unsplash.com/random/300x400">
<img src="https://source.unsplash.com/random/200x200">
<img src="https://source.unsplash.com/random/194x321">
```

---

**Updated alternative following additional information from the comments:**

This version uses the `darken` blend mode, which effectively chooses the darkest pixel between the image and the background's values at any given pixel. The result is that pixels which are darker than the background color remain visible, while lighter colored pixels are replaced by those from the background. This can have varying success based on the image though. To ensure a little more shines through, the example uses a brightness filter to make the images contain more areas of white for greater effect.

```css
.container {
    background:#FFF0E0;
}

img {
    mix-blend-mode:darken;
    filter:grayscale(1) brightness(1.1);
}

img:hover {
    filter:none;
    mix-blend-mode:normal;
}






/* ------- Layout Stuff. Ignore ------- */
body {
    display:flex;
}

img {
    flex:0 0 30%;
    width:30%;
    height:auto;
  box-sizing:border-box;
    padding:10px;
}

.container {
  box-sizing:border-box;
    max-width:80%;
    padding:50px;
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap:wrap;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    margin:50px auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
<!-- hand-curated images     -->
    <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1609081144293-c3e38b5c83a2" alt="">
    <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1608000208944-61c421ee6b33" alt="">
    <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1607283894277-e86fb9a5a2b8" alt="">
    
<!-- random images   -->
    <img src="https://source.unsplash.com/random/200x200">
    <img src="https://source.unsplash.com/random/194x321">
    <img src="https://source.unsplash.com/random/300x400">
</div>
```

Comment: Hey Riley, thank you so much for you response!! I'm really struggling with CSS so I appreciate it greatly. Unfortunately I was having issues getting the code to work on my site... The tint works well but the greyscale filter didn't seem to be working, this could be down to how cargo handles images.

Comment: I should have added this onto my initial post, here is an example of how it looks now...           [ https://ibb.co/C0mV3KS - Using your code ]
          [ https://ibb.co/Q9SBjGH - With whole site filter (ideally the aesthetic to match) ]
          [ https://ibb.co/18tvXsJ - Example of article page with black background... may not be possible with the solution as you noted. ]         Are there any other potential solutions to try out? Thank you very much!

Comment: @AlexanderPollard updated with a new example.